# Facebook login onClick - Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have this code on my website. The facebook login dialog is being shown when my page has loaded and not when the user has click on an anchor tag.

```
<script>
  // Additional JS functions here
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//192.168.1.127/test/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional init code here
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // connected
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // not_authorized
        login();
      } else {
        // not_logged_in
       login();
      }
    });
  };

  function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        testAPI() ;
      } else {
        // cancelled
      }
    });
  }

  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
</script>
```

I want the `FB.getLoginStatus` event to be fired up whenever the user click on this:

```
<a href = "#" onClick = "FB.getLoginStatus()">Login</a>
```

But right now it's being loaded without me doing anythings.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok so there is a simple solution here - wrap the call to `FB.getLoginStatus` in another function and have your button call *that* function.

```
function doLogin(){
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    ...
  };
}
```

Then you can change the `onClick` on your button to `doLogin()`.

Bassicaly, what was happening here is that as soon as the Facebook SDK is loaded, it calls the `window.fbAsyncInit` function which contained your `FB.getLoginStatus` code, so as soon as the SDK was ready, the login code was being executed.